# Jquery change a word to link on type

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

Is there a way that I can change a word to a link when keyup? For example, I want to convert all

> programming

into

```
 <a title="best programming help"
         href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">programming</a>
```

After you typed "programming" and another space. How can this be done?

---

Supplement: I'm typing this into a text area. (I'm using http://imperavi.com/redactor/, it's a plugin actually.)

I can have HTML in text area because I'm referring to the output of the text area. And technically, I'm using a wysiwyg :)

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Where are you typing this? Into a content-editable `<div>`, or an `<input>` or `<textarea>`? The latter two don't know anything except how to show text; they can't interpret HTML.

Comment: If you're typing in to a text input/textarea, how can you add HTML to the value?

Comment: You mean a bit like how you can type tags here on SO?

Comment: @Rory maybe a preview section like the one you see when you type an answer on StackOVerflow.

Comment: @nevercode I agree, but until OP clarifies any answer will be a pure guess at the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with the link being written out in plain text into the same element that you are typing into, this might do the trick for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/paulinfrancis/XFA4e/

```
var $thetext = $('#the-text');
var typedText = '';
var replaceText = '<a title="best programming help" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/">programming</a>';
var programmingRegex = /programming$/gi;

$thetext.on('keyup', function(data){   
    typedText = $thetext.val();

    var matches = typedText.match(programmingRegex); 
    if(matches){
        typedText = typedText.replace(programmingRegex, replaceText);
        $thetext.val(typedText);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to re-check the code. I moved the declaration of the regex out of the event handler.

Comment: actually man there is a small problem. I notice  that if I type "ask programming question" really quick without stop for like half a second after the word "programming", it won't convert occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their API they have this callback:

```
changeCallback: function(html)
    {
        console.log(html);
    }
```

which is fired everytime the content of the textarea changes.

You could search for the words you want in `html` and modify the words you find into links.

Comment: I can't do search and replace because it may mess up keywords which are already in the a tag? Thanks for ur help:)

Comment: I am not sure what the final implementation looks like, but this is the idea that first came to my mind. Well, maybe when you search also make sure the keyword is not enclosed in `<a>` tags

Comment: thanks for ur help. But I'm sure there is a way like after ur keyup with a specific word, it will convert stuff for u since that's how most editors concert URL to a tag?